# set environment variables mac using zsh for dotnet

Tags: .net, macos, zsh

So I just installed .net and they displayed a message about opting out of telemetry by setting the environment variable "DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT" to 1 or true

I dont care too much but I got curious so I looked it up but most articles are old and talk about editing the .bash_profile. But the shell is zsh

How would I, in this instance, opt out of telemetry?

Comment: You should search for existing discussions on https://unix.stackexchange.com zsh has its own configuration system, hinted in articles like https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh-part-2-configuration-files/

Comment: You set it up, wherever it suits you. Reading the _zshall_ man-page, in particular the section _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_, you will see which files are automatically processed based on what kind of zsh you are running. BTW, I would consider setting the variable in `~/.zshenv`, but this is a mattter of taste.